# How to make a collapsible fieldset in my theme?

Tags: 7, forms

I want to have collapsible fieldsets in my Drupal 7 website in add content. I added this in `html.tpl.php` of my theme:

```
<?php 
print $styles;
drupal_add_js('misc/form.js');
    drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js');

?>
```

But nothing happend to my fieldsets.
Here's a sample code of fieldset I have used:

```
<fieldset id="fieldset-id" class="collapsible">
  <legend><span class="fieldset-legend">Fieldset title</span></legend>
  <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
  <div class="fieldset-description">Fieldset description</div>
     Fieldset content
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: do you have any js errors ? - check console

Answer (score 1):

Your theme might include jQuery 1.9. With this, I observed in Drupal 7.34 that fieldsets would not work (always shown collapsed, unclickable). Also CKEditor would not load (using the [`ckeditor`](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module) and there might be other JavaScript related misbehavior.

To solve this, use jQuery 1.8 instead. I recommend the module [`jquery_update`](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) to handle jQuery versions in Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the libraries are others.

This example works for me:

```
$fieldset = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#attached' => array(
          'library' => array(
            array('system', 'drupal.collapse'),
          ),
        ),
        '#attributes' => array(
          'class' => array('collapsible', 'collapsed')
          ),
        ),
     );
```

Read more about this at [Fieldsets in D7, collapsed and collapsible not working](https://www.drupal.org/node/1090282).

Answer (score 0):

You should do that using the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7).

Here's an example implementation through a custom module:

```
/**
 * Sample form.
 */
function MYMODULE_sample_form() {
  $form['sample'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Sample fieldset'),
    '#description' => t('Sample fieldset description'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['sample']['sample_textfield'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Text field'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Submit the form'));

  return $form;
}
```

To display the form above, use the following code:

```
<?php
$form = drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_sample_form');
print drupal_render($form);
?>
```

However, it's not quite clear where exactly you want to display this. Sounds as if you want to alter some node creation form; if that is the case, post a comment and I'll update the example code.